# (picture) VS2015 How can I make this little bar show up?

Tags: visual-studio

This thing shows up on my laptop but it doesn't on my PC.
It's really helpful so I would really appreciate your help.
Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option can be set at Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> "Navigation Bar."